# Array not appending images

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm trying to append images to a 2Dimensional array. This is how I am doing it right now:

```
var imgArr1: [UIImage] = []
var imgArr2: [UIImage] = []

var allArrays = [imgArr1, imgArr2]

for array in 0 ..< allArrays.count {
    for i in categories { //list of folder names used below
        for img in fileNames("path/to/my/images/i") { //fileNames() returns all the files' names it finds in the folders
            print(img) //this does print out the correct file names, for instance: "img_1.jpg"
            allArrays[array].append(UIImage(named: img))
        }
    }
}
print(imgArr1) //this prints: "[]"`
```

We can assume that the loops and custom functions are working. (Note my comments in the code: the image names are correctly printed out.)

I already tried other methods to append the new image to the array, like `insert at index` and using `+=`.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: My guess is that `UIImage(named:img)` doesn't work. Use `imageWithContentsOfFile:` instead since it's a path not a image name that you are using as parameter.

Comment: I thought that might be the problem too but when I do `print(UIImage(named: img))` it prints the properties of the image (at least some number and the size). I also tried with and without file name extension.

Comment: The problem here is swift array is of value type, It is copied always. if you check your `allArrays` it will contain the images but imgArr1 is empty.

Comment: So what am I gonna do about it?

Comment: `for array in 0 ..< allArrays` gives error?

Comment: Nope doesn't. Forgot to post the `.count` in the question.

Comment: `var allArrays = [imgArr1, imgArr2]` means that `allArrays` will contain two arrays? or `allArrays ` will contain the content of two arrays? Also what is the `type` of `allArrays`?

Comment: `allArrays` contains two arrays which each contain a set of images. It is of type `[[UIImage]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for var array in allArrays
```

makes a mutable copy of the array. Appending to it won't mutate the original array, because arrays are value types. You'll have to add the images to `imgArr1` (or `imgArr2`, or both) directly in order for this to work.

**Edit**: As an example on how to do this, you can loop through the indices of the outer array and modify the inner arrays using subscripts:

```
var all: [[Int]] = [[], [], []]

for arrayIndex in 0 ..< all.count {
    for number in 0 ..< 10 {
        all[arrayIndex].append(number)
    }
}

print(all.first!.count) // 10
```

Comment: Right but it complains when I remove the `var`. So how am I gonna take the copy's contents and assign them to the original?

Comment: You'd have to add them to the original directly.

Comment: Come on. There's gotta be a way to do that. I have 13 arrays, I can't make a for loop for each one! I tried looping using `for array in 0 ..< allArrays` instead of using `for var array in allArrays` and then adding the image to `allArrays[array]`. No success :(

Comment: You mean `for array in 0 ..< allArrays.count`? That should work just fine. How are you appending the items?

Comment: Oops, yes. Like this: `allArrays[array].append(UIImage(named: img)!)`. When I print the arrays inside `allArrays`, they are still empty though.

Comment: That's strange. Have a look at my edit, I hope it clears things up :)

Comment: That definitely is strange. When printing, I just changed `print(imgArr1.count)`which still gives me 0 to `print(allArrays.first!.count)` which returns 5. How come? And that means that I can't access the array's arrays, right?

Comment: Ok. Workaround: in another function I assigned the array's values to the `allArrays[i]`'s values. Seems pointless but works. That way I can access each array individually. Thanks for your help!